# Seeing What is Running on a Progress Open Edge Database

Tags: openedge

I am trying to resolve some connectivity issues between Business Objects and a Progress Open Edge database.

I am trying to find a system table (or tables) that can tell me what is running on the progress open edge database. I only have ODBC access to it.

Special bonus points if the running sql can be returned!

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the "client statement cache".

This is available in 10.1C and higher.  Once enabled for a session it will track the database access statements (SQL queries for SQL connections or 4gl stack trace for 4gl connections) as they occur.  Is does not keep a history -- only the most recent statement is available.

I am a 4GL guy so you will have to excuse my SQL ineptitude but you can use SQL connections to fiddle with system tables.

The _Connect VST is what you are looking for.  For best results use the _Connect-Id key which is "off by one" from the Usr# (Id fields on VST tables are indexed, no other fields are).

If you have access to the server, you can enable the client statement cache via PROMON.  Select the "R&D" menu, then option 1, then option 18.  Choose "1-Single" for SQL connections.

If you want to code it with SQL you need to muck about with the _Connect. _connect-cachingType and _Connect._connect-cacheinfo[1] fields.

_connect-cachingType = 1  will give you your most recent SQL statement (or 4gl statement if it is a 4gl connection)

_connect-cacheinfo is an array.  element 1 is the only element with anything in it for SQL connection.  (4gl connections may have a procedure stack trace...)

Answer (score 1):

OE Databases have what is termed a "Statement Cache."

There's a KB on the technology [here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P150383?q=Client%20Database-Request%20Statement%20Cache&l=en_US&c=Product_Group%3AOpenEdge&type=Article__kav&fs=Search&pn=1), and a discussion on accessing the cache information via the database's VST tables [here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P145378?q=Client%20Database-Request%20Statement%20Cache&c=Product_Group%3AOpenEdge&type=Article__kav&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1).